# Embed a browser window within a Flash movie

Tags: html, flash, uiwebview

My question of the day is: in the same way a UIWebView on XCode behaves, is it possible to embed a website or browser window in an Adobe Flash movie? Like an iframe, but within Flash itself.

Is this even technically possible? Do I even want to attempt this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AIR got a HTML/Browser component that would allow you to do that. Flash itself doesn't support HTML outside a very basic set of commands, but you can use javascript to control a HTML layer above your flash movie. That's likely also what the below mentioned flex component does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true answer is no.

But there are workarounds, one of them is the [Flex Iframe](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/) mentioned above.

The workaround is based on a real iFrame rendered by JavaScript above the Flash and smart communication between Flash and that JavaScript.

The big drawback though is the **wmode=opaque** you have to use in order to enable anything to render above the Flash. There are accessibility issues, performance issues and even stability issues associated with the opaque mode, however sometimes you got to do what you got to do.

Check my [question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451168/wmode-and-flash-video-stability-and-performance), especially note the Adobe Flash Player Bug and Issue link, do some investigation first to make sure it won't kill your project.

Comment: Daniel thanks for your answer, it seems you already did some thorough research. Personally your answer helped me the most.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that it is possible. I have come across a few examples in the past, but never done it myself.

This link might help you with your research...
http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/

as might this, which has an explanation and further links...
http://www.deitte.com/archives/2008/07/dont_use_iframe.htm

I don't know how up to date this content is though.